# Laravel How to call a function with a if else

Tags: php, laravel, function, email

Im trying to make a function where if the date from the database is past the current date to send an email to the user. My email function works. Now I also already build that if the date is past the current date it adds a `<td>` with 'paste current date'. Now I would like to know if its possible to also send out an email to the user?.

This is my code

```
<td class="wrong">
 @php  
     $date = new DateTime($i->EindDatum);
     $now = new DateTime();

     if($date < $now)  echo  'past current date' 
 @endphp
 @if ($date < $now)
 {{ $users = User::find(1)  $user->notify(new TaksComplete)}}
 @endif
</td>
```

Now the @if function returns this error `syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'>`

I know the application doesnt know User because its a function but I dont know how to fix that.

The function does work because when I for example use it in my routes/web.php it does work like this:

```
Route::get('/hosting', function(){

    $users = User::find(1);
    Notification::send($users, new TaksComplete);
    return view('hosting');

} );
```

This does send an email to the user when it clicks /hosting but I did that just for testing

ps. I am new to laravel

Comment: {{ $users = User::find(1)  $user->notify(new TaksComplete)}}  change this line of code @

Comment: To what ? should I change the line of code?

Comment: @try this @{{ $users = User::find(1) }} {{$user->notify(new TaksComplete)}}

Comment: May I ask why you are doing all of this in your view? Shouldn't that be done in the controller method?

Comment: Also: `$users` != `$user`

Comment: @kerbholz you are right.. I did not think of that. Stupid me but I also dont really now how to put php code in my controller to be honest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax error in your view fil. In your `{{ }}` brackets you are writing assignment and then missing semicolon there.

You can write this logic without leaving first `@php` tags.

```
@php  
    $date = new DateTime($i->EindDatum);
    $now = new DateTime();

    if($date < $now)  echo  'past current date';

    if ($date < $now) {
        $user = App\User::find(1);
        $user->notify(new App\Notifications\TaksComplete);
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: This gives me the error **Class 'User' not found** where should I import the class?

Comment: You can write absolute path `App\User` instaead of user and also absolute path for your  `TaksComplete` class

Comment: Thanks this worked.. But now my function is sending an email everytime the page loads. This might be offtopic but do you know how to send the email just once? Also say I have 2 dates in my database wich are past date it will send the email twice..

Comment: You can add one column in users table if email is sent or not

Comment: Im sorry but how would that work? How can I make like a function where it fills the column so it knows it already send an email?

Comment: When you're done sending email you can update email_send column: `$user->update(['email_send' =>  1])`. note that you have to add it firs in database and then in fillable property. then check if `email_send` is 0 and only send email if so

Comment: So dont change anything in the function? just that and it will work? And should I make the email_send column a boolean?

Comment: Yes, you have to make changes if you want something to work. you have to write conditions and updates which i wrote above

Comment: I know I am sorry. But how do I change the fillable property? so it only sends if email_send = 0 ?

Comment: $fillable property is in User class.

Comment: so what Should i change in the $fillable class? Looks like this now: 'name', 'email', 'password', 'email_send'

Comment: add column name which you have added in database

Comment: And i get this error now syntax error, unexpected '$user'

Comment: I did the column name which I have added in the database is: email_send

Comment: So any idea ? @Malkhazi Dartsmelidze

Comment: Im sorry but should the email_send be in the user table or in the SSL(the one im reading data from now) table?

Comment: I put the email_send in my SSL table but it wont change from 0 to 1 in the database

Comment: When I put email_send in my users table it does update.. but I cant read data from the users table because in my model i have this: protected $table='SSL'; any idea how to add like 2 tables in a model or how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

keep doing calculation in `@php` tag only don't split

```
@php  
 $date = new DateTime($i->EindDatum);
 $now = new DateTime();

 if($date < $now)  echo  'past current date';

 if ($date < $now) {
    $user = /App/User::find(1)->first();
    $user->notify(new TaksComplete);
 }
 @endphp
```

Comment: fixed try it now